# How to express the inverse of matrix $(I+A)^{-1}$ if $A$ is non-invertible?

Tags: linear-algebra

I ran into a square matrix of the form:

$$\mathbf{I}+\mathbf{A}$$

where $\mathbf{A}$ is non-invertible.  How do I express the inverse of this matrix $\mathbf{I}+\mathbf{A}$?

Comment: There's no guarantee that $I+A$ is invertible either.

Comment: @carmichael561 When does the power series $1-A+A^2-A^3+\dots$ converge for this one?

Comment: Try applying fornula for geometric series to your matrix $A$

Comment: @Vlad Isn't that what I said above?

Comment: If one of the eigenvalues of $A$ is $-1$, this matrix cannot be invertible. So having $A$ non-invertible isn't really the right criterion.

Comment: Ok I thought there would be a simple result for this matrix; but obviously there's not.  Either, someone answer with a negative and I quickly accept, or close this question as too trivial.

Comment: @ParclyTaxel Pretty much the same, just worded differently/more explicitly

Comment: In case $\lVert A \rVert < 1$ then you should be able to use the geometric series.

Comment: See http://www.math.uvic.ca/~dcwatson/work/geometric.pdf . Similar to what @DanielSchepler stated if the spectral radius (largest eigenvalue) < 1, then the geometric series converges.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on @QuantumDot's comment I will go ahead and "officially" assert that there is no general formula and that in some cases both $A $ and $I+A $ may be noninvertible.  If $A$ is a 2×2 matrix with a zero top row and $-1$ in the second row, second column, then both $A $ and $I+A $ are noninvertible.

If $A $ is *triangular* with all diagonal elements zero, then $(I+A)^{-1} $ is easy to find: the geometric series sum terminates.

Comment: More generally, the sum has a finite number of terms if $A$ is nilpotent.

Answer (score 4):

Let $P(\lambda) = \det(\lambda I - A)$ be the characteristic polynomial of $A$.
This is a polynomial of degree $n$, where $A$ is $n \times n$.
Now $$\frac{P(t) - P(-1)}{t+1} = R(t)$$ 
is a polynomial of degree $n-1$.  By the Cayley-Hamilton theorem $P(A) = 0$,
and  $-P(-1) = (A+I) R(A)$.  $A+I$ is invertible if and only if $P(-1) \ne 0$, in which case $(A+I)^{-1} = -R(A)/P(-1)$.

Answer (score 0):

we have the fact that not invertible matrix is diagonalizable, in other words the matrix is diagonalizable with a value in the diagonal equal to $0$:
$$(I+A)^{-1}=(P^{-1}P+P^{-1}DP)^{-1}=(P^{-1}(I+D)P)^{-1}=P(I+D)^{-1}P^{-1}$$
now the determinat has to be not equal to $0$:
$$\det(P(I+D)^{-1}P^{-1})=\det(I+D)^{-1}=\frac{1}{\det(I+D)}$$
then $\det(I+D)\not=0$.Is obviusly for the fact that element in the diagonal are $\not=$ to zero.$$$$
God bless us