Closed form formula for $(\mathbb I+R)^{-1}$ where $R$ is an orthogonal matrix?
Is there a closed form formula for $(\mathbb I+R)^{-1}$, where $R$ is an orthogonal matrix?
There are formulas for inverse of matrix sums, but I couldn't find one that evaluated to a simple result.
After some experimentation in Mathematica I found expressions of the form
\begin{align}
\tfrac 1 2\mathbb I+c(R-R^T)\\
\end{align}
where
\begin{align}
c=\frac{n-\text{tr}(R)}{2(\text{tr}\left(R^2\right)-n)}
\end{align}
seems to work $n=2,3$ in $\mathbb R^n$, but I have no clue how.
Any help?

If $-1$ is an eigenvalue of $R$, $\mathbb I + R$ is not invertible.  Otherwise, let $P(x)= \det(x\mathbb I - R)$ be the characteristic polynomial of $R$.
Note that $P(-1) = \det(-\mathbb I - R) \ne 0$. Let
$$Q(x) = \frac{P(x) - P(-1)}{x+1}$$ which is a polynomial in $x$.  Then
$$(\mathbb I + R)^{-1} = - Q(R) /P(-1) $$
This works for all square matrices $R$ that do not have $-1$ as an eigenvalue, not just the orthogonal ones.

Notably, this explains the expressions that OP found since the characteristic polynomial is given by
$$
P(x) = x^2 - \text{tr}(R) x + \det(R)
$$
in the case that $n = 2$ and
$$
P(x) = x^3 - \operatorname{tr}(R)x^2 + \frac{\operatorname{tr}^2(R) - \operatorname{tr}(R^2)}{2} x + \det(R),
$$
where we note that $\det R \in {\pm 1}$ for orthogonal matrices $R$. Importantly, $I + R$ being invertible necessitates that $\det(R) = 1$ when $n = 3$.

[+1] for the answer and also for the comment by @Ben Grossmann

Similar to https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2298326/305862 but it isn't an issue.

To add to my comment, actually $I + R$ being invertible also implies that $\det(R) = 1$ in the case that $n = 2$.

Do I understand this correctly: if $P(x)-P(1)$ contains a factor $(x+1)$ this expression simplifies nicely, i.e. everything is expressed as a polynomial in powers of $R$ and maybe inverses of $R$. If that is not the case, we are out of luck and we have to evaluate $1/(x+1)$ at $x=R$, i.e. we have to calculate $(\mathbb I+R)^{-1}$ anyway. If that is the case, under which conditions can we factor out $(x+1)$?

It's not $P(1)$, it's $P(-1)$.  For any polynomial $P$ and any $a$, the polynomial $P(x) - P(a)$ is always divisible by $x-a$.  This is the case $a = -1$.

@RobertIsrael Didn't know that. But after taking a look it's almost trivial. I have now accepted this as an answer
